# Find and replace dynamic value from Array using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to find string `Page 1 0f 5`, `Page 2 0f 5`, `Page 3 0f 5` from array and replace with space?At this time i added static condition but can i make it dynamic?

```
var arr = ["Page 1 0f 5","Page Cat", "Boy", "Page 2 0f 5", "Page 3 0f 5", "Page 4 0f 5", "Apple"];
    var myarray = [];
    for(var n=0;n<arr.length-1;n++){
        console.log(arr[n]);
        if(arr[n]!='Page 1 0f 5' || arr[n]!='Page 2 0f 5' || arr[n]!='Page 3 0f 5'){
            myarray.push(arr[n]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You actually created new array, not replacing the items with space (as you stated above), but by removing those items instead. Please also be accurate, items may be `Page 3 of 100`, correct?

Comment: @skobaljic  Yes page can be `Page 3 of 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this dynamically, try and use some [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

EG:

```
var arr = ["Page 1 0f 5","Page Cat", "Boy", "Page 2 0f 5", "Page 3 0f 5", "Page 4 0f 5", "Apple"];

var filteredArray = [];

for(var n=0;n<arr.length-1;n++){
 //matching any with Page ___ 0f ___
 res = arr[n].match(/Page [0-9]+ 0f [0-9]+/g);
 if(!res){
     //if it didn't find the string put it in your filteredArray
     filteredArray.push(arr[n]);
 }
}

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Correct one, similar on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/813b2aov/4/).

Answer (score 0):

check it man.?

```js
var arr = ["Page 1 0f 5","Page Cat", "Boy", "Page 2 0f 5", "Page 3 0f 5", "Page 4 0f 5","Apple"];
    var myarray = [];
    for(var n=0;n<arr.length-1;n++){
        console.log(arr[n]);
        debugger;
        if(arr[n]!='Page 1 0f 5' && arr[n]!='Page 2 0f 5' && arr[n]!='Page 3 0f 5'){
            myarray.push(arr[n]);
            
        }
    }
    console.log(myarray)
```